# PHP confirmation email link is takes me to the wrong page

Tags: php, email, activation

I have a php script :)
Basically users signup receive an email and click on an activation link. When they click on the activation link it takes them to the activate.php page and all is done.
The problem the link in the email they receive looks like

Hello username, Now here is your login info:

username: computing
password: computing
**The next step is to click on this link to activate your account: CLICK HERE**

You can see in the last line above that the name of there website is joined to the activate.php page the link is supposed to take them to. So im guessing my error is not so bad and I'm just missing forward slash or something like that.
Anyway I think the problem comes from the code below. I have kept the code short as possible.

```
<?

// send email
$myname = $contact_name;
$myemail = $contact_email;

$contactname = $signup[fname];
$contactemail = $signup[email];
$message = "Hello ".$signup[fname].",<BR>".
"Get ready to start getting the hits you deserve. Now here is your login info:<BR>     <BR>".
"username: ".$signup[username]."<BR>".
"password: ".$signup[password]."<BR><BR>".
"<B>The next step is to click on this link to activate your account:<a href=".$siteUrl."activate.php?username=".$signup[username].">CLICK HERE</a></b>";
$subject = $title;

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$myname." <".$myemail.">\r\n";
$headers .= "To: ".$contactemail." <".$contactemail.">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$myname." <".$myemail.">\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";
$headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: Just My Server";

mail($contactemail, $subject, $message, $headers);
$signup[username] = "";
?>
```

If anyone can shed some light on this it would be good. Thought I would just mention I am using PHP 5.3
I think myself the problem comes from
href=".$siteUrl."activate.php?username=".$signup[username].">CLICK HERE";
$subject = $title;

But I need some valid input :) from some one who knows.

Comment: For security purposes are you hashing the passwords also you might want to not send clear-text passwords. You might want to add token activation eg: example.com/activate.php/?token=dhwudf983nsdfwuen&user=nwenwsli2nf82ndj and have that check the user and token and then you'll know thats the user that actually clicked the link

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will be creating a separate thread about this later. Because like you say the security side is very lame. So you feel free to jump in on it. Regards Nige.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed when you assign your link you used .$siteUrl. have you actually set that variable?

Also since you would be comming from an outside source (e-mail hosting website) it would work just as fine to "hard-code" your link as your full website address. Ex:

```
<a href="http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourdirectories/activate.php?username=".$signup[username].">Click Here</a>
```

So a value of your message value could be.

```
$message = "Hello ".$signup[fname].",<BR>".
"Get ready to start getting the hits you deserve. Now here is your login info:<BR>     <BR>".
"username: ".$signup[username]."<BR>".
"password: ".$signup[password]."<BR><BR>".
"<B>The next step is to click on this link to activate your account:<a href='http://www.yourwebsite.comactivate.php?username=".$signup[username]."'>CLICK HERE</a></b>";
```

You shouldn't have a problem with the double slashes but if you have a problem with those you can use:

```
$message = "Hello ".$signup[fname].",<BR>".
"Get ready to start getting the hits you deserve. Now here is your login info:<BR>     <BR>".
"username: ".$signup[username]."<BR>".
"password: ".$signup[password]."<BR><BR>".
"<B>The next step is to click on this link to activate your account:<a  href='http:/"."/www.yourwebsite.com/activate.php?username=".$signup[username]."'>CLICK HERE</a></b>";
```

Comment: Hi Devon, I have just tried what you said but the problem I have when I try to implement this is where the web address starts IE http://  as soon as I do the 2 slashes my code becomes commented out. Is it possible for you to use my code above and implement lets say the last few lines so I can just do a copy and paste.     Cheers Nige

Comment: Thanks Devon, it 2.40 in the morning. I'm wacked and was refusing to go to bed till this was fixed. You fixed it. Thanks Nige

Comment: @user1906671: Thanks and I am glad to help, please remember to check my answer off as the solution so others know it is answered.

Answer (score 2):

You need a space between "a" and "href" in your message.

Also, all modern email clients automatically turn URLs into links, so it probably isn't necessary to use an href tag at all.

Comment: Hi Chris, that was my bad while pasting code here. There was a space between the "a" and "href" I have since corrected this for others to see. Thanks Nige.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's inside the string "s you need to escape them or use single-quotes.

Here's a fixed version:

```
$message = "Hello ".$signup[fname].",<br>".
  "Get ready to start getting the hits you deserve. Now here is your login info:<br>     <br>".
  "username: ".$signup[username]."<br>".
  "password: ".$signup[password]."<br><br>".
  "<b>The next step is to click on this link to activate your account: 
  <a href='".$siteUrl."activate.php?username=".$signup[username].'>CLICK HERE</a></b>";
```

Comment: Philip Whitehouse, Thanks for the reply I tried your code and I get this error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE in D:\hosting\7560507\html\fast\traffic1\reg.php on line 157                                                                                                                                              Line 157 is the last line of code you provide.